# run jupiter notebook on click of a button

Tags: javascript, python

I have designed UI using Javascript, HTML and CSS. Now I want to run jupiter notebook in backend when I will click on some particular button in UI.
Can anyone help me with this?
Right now I am thinking to use flask to do the same.

Comment: You wouldn't use Jupyter -- that's a UI.  You would run a Python script with no UI.  Flask is a fine choice for a framework.

Comment: Thanks Robert...can you help me to store the result of this python script in a particular format, instead displaying it over the screen.

Comment: Store it where?  In a database?  In a file?

Comment: In a database. Actually the requirement is when the result is generated it should get stored in database and the user should get notified about the same.

Comment: That's fine.  That means you need to choose your database (it can be something like MySQL or sqlite3, or even a JSON file if the data is small).